# Weird behavior with socketIO and .NET clients

Tags: c#, websocket, uwp, socket.io

I'm using socketIO on node and hook it up with the front-end, they work fine 
Now I want to push things further

I want my .net clients (UWP) communicate with the socketIO 
But there is something really weird happening

At first I tested and it run just fine, the second time I run the client
It started to send twice or more messages when I only send one. And I realize that if I open the .net client first and the server later this won't happen, but when I shut my clients down (while the server still running) this bug started to happen.

```
public sealed partial class StuffDetail : Page
 {
    Socket socket = IO.Socket("ws://localhost:8888");
    ObservableCollection<SocketMessage> InCommingData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SocketMessage>();
    public StuffDetail()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DisconnectState();
        SetSocket();
        ChatWindow.ItemsSource = InCommingData;
    }

    private void DisconnectState()
    {
        ReceivedText.Text = "Not Connect";
    }



    private void SetSocket()
    {
        socket.Connect();
        ReceivedText.Text = "Connect Completed";

        socket.On("chat", async (data) =>
        {

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var IncomeMess = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocketMessage>(data.ToString());
                InCommingData.Add(IncomeMess);
            });

        });


    }



    private void Send(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = new SocketMessage()
        {
            message = MessTextBox.Text,
            handle = "From Beta User"
        };
        socket.Emit("chat", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you disconnected server before the app shut down with `StreamSocket.Dispose()` method?

Comment: I did put socket.Disconnect() below the IncommingData.Add(IncomMess);. But don't seem to fix the issue

Comment: Could you share a mini sample that could reproduce the issue. it sounds like a bug.

Comment: you can test the connection with https://firecamp.app

Comment: What's your client uwp app?

Comment: Yes it's a bug not from SocketIO but the Quobject nuget package